# React- How to use both locally scoped css and css from third party components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, css-modules, react-css-modules

I am locally scoping my css files by using

```
modules: true,
localIdentName: "[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
```

in webpack.config.dev and prod.js. I am able to use the styles i have defined for the components using import style from './Component.css'.
Now i am trying to use the react-select third party component. Now the  component has its predefined style which i want to use. To use it i import the style as follows

import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css'

But the style doesn't gets applied. How to enable the predefined style for the imported component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [`resource query`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-resourcequery) to treat CSS imports differently depending on the query.

This way you could import your regular CSS with the `?external` query parameter.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /.css$/,
        oneOf: [
          {
            // import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css?external'
            resourceQuery: /external/, 
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
          },
          {
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            options: {
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]_[hash:base64:5]'
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: I am new to this so my questions might seem silly. In the webpack.config.dev.js i am going to add the following rule-'{
            // import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css?external'
            resourceQuery: /external/, 
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
          },'                                                                                                                     Now in the <Select /> component how to use the ?external query parameter? Or do i have to use the ?external in my own build components?

Comment: I think i got your hint. In external component <Select/> i have to use import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css?external' after adding the above rule. Let me know if i am incorrect and i am going to try it. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @Braj The comment in my answer, `import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css?external'`, was just an example of how to use it in your app. If you import a CSS file with `?external` at the end of the file name, Webpack will treat that as regular CSS and not CSS modules. Just write `import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css?external'` once in your App, and the `react-select` CSS will be part of your CSS as expected.

Comment: I am gonna try it and update you. Also will covering the webpack topic give me insight into how webpack works in relation with css and other files?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.